# Is this a syntax error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
IF( @ActiveStatus = 1 )
BEGIN 
    @PasswordStatus = 3 
END
ELSE 
    SET @PasswordStatus = (SELECT password_status 
                             FROM tbl_user
                            WHERE login_name = @LoginName_fromApp
                              AND password=@Pass
                           )
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio..

Comment: mysql and mssql different dbms, I've changed the tag!

Comment: hey dont forget to mark it as accepte or upvote it if the solution works for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes

In `IF` clause you need to set variable so use `select` or `set`, do not write directly `@PasswordStatus = 3` write `set/select @PasswordStatus = 3`

try

```
if( @ActiveStatus = 1 ) 
begin 
--chage of code 

 set @PasswordStatus = 3 --or select @PasswordStatus = 3
   END
else 
begin
Set @PasswordStatus = (select password_status from tbl_user where  login_name=@LoginName_fromApp and password=@Pass)

end
```

**EDIT**

**Comment of -@ marc_s** Use SET @Var = 3 if you're just setting a "scalar" value - use SELECT @Var = ID FROM dbo.Table1 if you're actually selecting from a table (or view)

Comment: Use `SET @Var = 3` if you're just setting a "scalar" value - use `SELECT @Var = ID FROM dbo.Table1` if you're actually selecting from a table (or view)

Answer (score 0):

when you r setting valuer to any variable use **Set** as followed

```
if( @ActiveStatus = 1 )
begin
Set @PasswordStatus = 3 
END
else 
begin
Set @PasswordStatus = (select password_status from tbl_user where
login_name=@LoginName_fromApp and password=@Pass)
end
Select @PasswordStatus
```

Comment: I am not downvoter but I think you are poiting same mistake that i pointed in my answer..there is no change

Answer (score 0):

Another one

```
select 
        @PasswordStatus = case when @ActiveStatus = 1 then 3 else password_status  end
from 
    tbl_user  
where  
        login_name = @LoginName_fromApp and password=@Pass
```